# Why does subreport show in SSDT but when moved to SSRS cannot view sub-report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm using SSDT-BI 2012 to create a report. I've tested connections and in SSDT-BI in my preview version I can view and see all of the sub reports in my "container".

However when I move this into SSRS I get Error:Subreport counld not be shown.

Any help as always would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Is the subreport in the same folder on SSRS as the parent report?

Comment: Hi, I've worked it out, was the issue you stated. Thanks